# How to animate a custom Google Maps marker along a route?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, handheld

I have written a small application for a handheld device using JavaScript and Google Maps API's, now II need to move my marker icon anywhere on the map along a route using a timer function. I have a man icon and I need to move it automatically on the map. How can I do this?

Comment: I edited the title to reflect the contents of the question. @jyothi: when posting a question, please take your time to review the contents of it. With just 2 minutes of extra reviewing, you can improve the quality by 100%, with an expectation of more and better answers.

Comment: k sir thank u, can u answer my question

Comment: @jyothi did you get a solution to this i need to do this exact same thing on a map application. Can you shed some light if you achieved it how it was achieved.

Answer (score 17):

A pretty cool example is here:

http://www.kmcgraphics.com/google/

Comment: That page uses an older version of the library at http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm which contains some handy utility functions you can use to find the lat-long of a position along a path.  Should make it much easier to build an animated marker.

Comment: Just out of interest I also used a similar technique on a site I buid last year. the methods are likely a little out of date with the latest APIs but it works well. http://www.flushtracker.com/

Comment: @Matt It looks like the domain **flushtracker.com** now redirects to **domestos.com/uk/home.html**.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there is no automatic-marker-movement function in the official GMaps collection.

However, if you have a GRoute, that would mean you have a set of points. To loop through the route steps, you could use something like this:

```
for (var c = 0; c < yourroute.getNumSteps(); c++) { 
    yourmarker.setLatLng(yourroute.getStep(c).getLatLng());
}
```

Of course, you'll probably want to do this asynchronously using the timers:

```
function moveToStep(yourmarker,yourroute,c) {
    if {yourroute.getNumSteps() > c) {
        yourmarker.setLatLng(yourroute.getStep(c).getLatLng());
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            moveToStep(yourmarker,yourroute,c+1);
        },500);
    }
}

moveToStep(marker,route,0);
```

For even smoother movement, you could interpolate the points from those you already have.

Comment: Is this functionality available in Google Maps V3? The "steps" array returned by the DirectionsService only seems to include the steps of the directions (ie turn left at so-and-so) instead of the individual points that make the rendered line.

Comment: @Puskvor is it possible to keep incrementing a latlong coordinate to simulate a route,the route doesn't have to be only on streets.

Comment: @dev_darin: Yes. Not all routes are straight lines though; in between the various route points, your approach is of course viable.

Comment: @Puskvor can you tell me how it can be incremented the long lat i know its based on an angle as well i was thinking about using a randomizer to get values but i would like to know how can it be incremented

Comment: @dav_durin: get one coordinate, increment it by a given amount, get the other, increment by some other amount, create a new LatLng with the new coordinates, .setLatLng(yourNewLatLng).

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution that works with the v3 API. This animates the marker not with a fixed velocity, but based on the calculated route duration. There is a speed factor, so for example you can drive through the route 10x faster than in reality.

I've tried to do it as simple as possible. Feel free to use it.

```
var autoDriveSteps = new Array();
var speedFactor = 10; // 10x faster animated drive

function setAnimatedRoute(origin, destination, map) {
    // init routing services
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map
    });

    //calculate route
    directionsService.route({
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        },
        function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                // display the route
                directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);

                // calculate positions for the animation steps
                // the result is an array of LatLng, stored in autoDriveSteps
                autoDriveSteps = new Array();
                var remainingSeconds = 0;
                var leg = response.routes[0].legs[0]; // supporting single route, single legs currently
                leg.steps.forEach(function(step) {
                    var stepSeconds = step.duration.value;
                    var nextStopSeconds = speedFactor - remainingSeconds;
                    while (nextStopSeconds <= stepSeconds) {
                        var nextStopLatLng = getPointBetween(step.start_location, step.end_location, nextStopSeconds / stepSeconds);
                        autoDriveSteps.push(nextStopLatLng);
                        nextStopSeconds += speedFactor;
                    }
                    remainingSeconds = stepSeconds + speedFactor - nextStopSeconds;
                });
                if (remainingSeconds > 0) {
                    autoDriveSteps.push(leg.end_location);
                }
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
}

// helper method to calculate a point between A and B at some ratio
function getPointBetween(a, b, ratio) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(a.lat() + (b.lat() - a.lat()) * ratio, a.lng() + (b.lng() - a.lng()) * ratio);
}

// start the route simulation   
function startRouteAnimation(marker) {
    var autoDriveTimer = setInterval(function () {
            // stop the timer if the route is finished
            if (autoDriveSteps.length === 0) {
                clearInterval(autoDriveTimer);
            } else {
                // move marker to the next position (always the first in the array)
                marker.setPosition(autoDriveSteps[0]);
                // remove the processed position
                autoDriveSteps.shift();
            }
        },
        1000);
}
```

Usage:

```
setAnimatedRoute("source address or LatLng ...", "destination address or LatLng ...", map);
// start simulation on button click...
$("#simulateRouteButton").click(function() {
    startRouteAnimation(agentMarker);
});
```

Comment: a very elegant solution. Thanks.