# Smooth natural animation in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to move/animate a long thin marker along a path in Google Maps, with it rotating as it turns corners. This is to simulate the movement of a train. I am hoping for a solution which will allow it to move smoothly.

Can people suggest approaches for browser based outputs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to animate a custom Google Maps marker along a route?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665193/how-to-animate-a-custom-google-maps-marker-along-a-route)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using Google Earth plugin instead? I know that this would be possible with the Google Earth Plugin, lots of examples here: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/demogallery