# Add animated PNG. to polyline in google maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to animate a icon over a polyline like in this example: https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate.

It works but I want to add my own PNG as the icon that is being animated. This is what I tried:

```
        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [{ lat: 25.774266, lng: -80.193659 }, { lat: 25.83333, lng: 25.83333 - 77.8999964 }],
            icons: [{
                icon: CruiseShip //This is my .PNG file
            }],
            strokeColor: '#ffffff',
            strokeWeight: 1,
            map: map
        });

        function animateCircle(line) {
            var count = 0;
            window.setInterval(function () {
                count = (count + 1) % 200;

                var icons = line.get('icons');
                icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
                line.set('icons', icons);
            }, 20);
        }
```

Using the lineSymbol object like in the example does work. How can I add a .PNG file to the polyline instead of the lineSymbol? Couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: related question: [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Marker Animation Based Off Known Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510324/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-marker-animation-based-off-known-route)

Comment: [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_xml.html), [example on polyline from KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_animateMarker_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/JBU181_20110102_kml.xml)

Comment: related question: [Animating Multiple Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245513/animating-multiple-markers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to animate the icon only works for SVG Symbols.

[Mike Williams](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/) wrote an extension to the Google Maps Javascript API v2 (now deprecated and turned off) called [epoly](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm) which contains the method `.GetPointAtDistance`, which can be used to update the position of a "normal" icon along a polyline.

There is a `interpolate` method in the `google.maps.geometry.spherical` library which interpolates between two points, but isn't very accurate for large scale features.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2tgm8qp4/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of
// the first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and Brisbane,
// Australia which was made by Charles Kingsford Smith.

function initMap() {
  updatePolylinePrototype();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: -180
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{
      lat: 25.774266,
      lng: -80.193659
    }, {
      lat: 25.83333,
      lng: 25.83333 - 77.8999964
    }, {
      lat: 28.411413,
      lng: -16.5449611
    }],
    strokeColor: '#ffffff',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    map: map
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: {
      url: "http://earth.google.com/images/kml-icons/track-directional/track-12.png",
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 12),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(24, 24),
    },
    position: line.getPath().getAt(0),
    map: map
  })

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < line.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(line.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  animateShip(line, marker);
}

function animateShip(line, marker) {
  var count = 0;
  var lineDistance = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < line.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    lineDistance += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(line.getPath().getAt(i - 1), line.getPath().getAt(i))
  }

  window.setInterval(function() {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;

    marker.setPosition(line.GetPointAtDistance(lineDistance - (lineDistance * count / 200)));
  }, 20);
}

function updatePolylinePrototype() {
  // === A method which returns a GLatLng of a point a given distance along the path ===
  // === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
  google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = function(metres) {
    // some awkward special cases
    if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
    if (metres < 0) return null;
    if (this.getPath().getLength() < 2) return null;
    var dist = 0;
    var olddist = 0;
    for (var i = 1;
      (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
      olddist = dist;
      dist += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this.getPath().getAt(i), this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
    }
    if (dist < metres) {
      return null;
    }
    var p1 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 2);
    var p2 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 1);
    var m = (metres - olddist) / (dist - olddist);
    return new google.maps.LatLng(p1.lat() + (p2.lat() - p1.lat()) * m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * m);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry">
</script>
```