# Is it possible to specify a route and then get a list of (long,lat) by specifying a percentage of the route?

Tags: google-maps

After specify a route with way points I would like to move along the route in increments (specified as a fraction of the total distance [0 to 1]) and build a list of (longitude, latitude) points.

What existing function in the API, if any, facilitate this slicing of the route?

Comment: I actually just found this after posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665193/how-to-animate-a-custom-google-maps-marker-along-a-route The issue was moving a marker along the route, this question is then equivalent (sort of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the [posted example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-timeOnRoute.html) to do straight distance (it had to be modified originally to do time...).  Uses a version of the [epoly library by Mike Williams](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm), ported to v3.  The key method being:

`.GetPointAtDistance(metres)` Returns the google.maps.LatLng of a point at the specified distance along the path.

```js
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var polyline = null;

function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
  // alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
  var contentString = '<b>' + label + '</b><br>' + html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: label,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });
  marker.myname = label;
  // gmarkers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  return marker;
}

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function calcRoute() {

  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: travelMode
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      polyline.setPath([]);
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      startLocation = new Object();
      endLocation = new Object();
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";

      // For each route, display summary information.
      var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
      var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
      for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
          startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
          // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
          marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green");
        }
        endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
        endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
        var steps = legs[i].steps;
        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
          var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
          for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
            polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
            bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
          }
        }
      }

      polyline.setMap(map);

      computeTotalDistance(response);
    } else {
      alert("directions response " + status);
    }
  });
}

var totalDist = 0;
var totalTime = 0;

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  totalDist = 0;
  totalTime = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
  }
  totalDist = totalDist / 1000.
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "total distance is: " + totalDist + " km<br>total time is: " + (totalTime / 60).toFixed(2) + " minutes";
  document.getElementById("totalTime").value = (totalTime / 60.).toFixed(2);
}

function putMarkerOnRoute(distance) {
  // alert("Time:"+time+" totalTime:"+totalTime+" totalDist:"+totalDist+" dist:"+distance);
  if (!marker) {
    marker = createMarker(polyline.GetPointAtDistance(distance), "distance: " + distance, "marker");
  } else {
    marker.setPosition(polyline.GetPointAtDistance(distance));
    marker.setTitle("distance:" + distance);
  }
}


/*********************************************************************\
*                                                                     *
* epolys.js                                          by Mike Williams *
* updated to API v3                                  by Larry Ross    *
*                                                                     *
* A Google Maps API Extension                                         *
*                                                                     *
* Adds various Methods to google.maps.Polygon and google.maps.Polyline *
*                                                                     *
* .Contains(latlng) returns true is the poly contains the specified   *
*                   GLatLng                                           *
*                                                                     *
* .Area()           returns the approximate area of a poly that is    *
*                   not self-intersecting                             *
*                                                                     *
* .Distance()       returns the length of the poly path               *
*                                                                     *
* .Bounds()         returns a GLatLngBounds that bounds the poly      *
*                                                                     *
* .GetPointAtDistance() returns a GLatLng at the specified distance   *
*                   along the path.                                   *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                   Reurns null if the path is shorter than that      *
*                                                                     *
* .GetPointsAtDistance() returns an array of GLatLngs at the          *
*                   specified interval along the path.                *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                                                                     *
* .GetIndexAtDistance() returns the vertex number at the specified    *
*                   distance along the path.                          *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                   Returns null if the path is shorter than that      *
*                                                                     *
* .Bearing(v1?,v2?) returns the bearing between two vertices          *
*                   if v1 is null, returns bearing from first to last *
*                   if v2 is null, returns bearing from v1 to next    *
*                                                                     *
*                                                                     *
***********************************************************************
*                                                                     *
*   This Javascript is provided by Mike Williams                      *
*   Blackpool Community Church Javascript Team                        *
*   http://www.blackpoolchurch.org/                                   *
*   http://econym.org.uk/gmap/                                        *
*                                                                     *
*   This work is licenced under a Creative Commons Licence            *
*   http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/uk/                    *
*                                                                     *
***********************************************************************
*                                                                     *
* Version 1.1       6-Jun-2007                                        *
* Version 1.2       1-Jul-2007 - fix: Bounds was omitting vertex zero *
*                                add: Bearing                         *
* Version 1.3       28-Nov-2008  add: GetPointsAtDistance()           *
* Version 1.4       12-Jan-2009  fix: GetPointsAtDistance()           *
* Version 3.0       11-Aug-2010  update to v3                         *
*                                                                     *
\*********************************************************************/

// === first support methods that don't (yet) exist in v3
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceFrom = function(newLatLng) {
  var EarthRadiusMeters = 6378137.0; // meters
  var lat1 = this.lat();
  var lon1 = this.lng();
  var lat2 = newLatLng.lat();
  var lon2 = newLatLng.lng();
  var dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = EarthRadiusMeters * c;
  return d;
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.latRadians = function() {
  return this.lat() * Math.PI / 180;
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.lngRadians = function() {
  return this.lng() * Math.PI / 180;
}

// === A method for testing if a point is inside a polygon
// === Returns true if poly contains point
// === Algorithm shamelessly stolen from http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/ 
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Contains = function(point) {
  var j = 0;
  var oddNodes = false;
  var x = point.lng();
  var y = point.lat();
  for (var i = 0; i < this.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    j++;
    if (j == this.getPath().getLength()) {
      j = 0;
    }
    if (((this.getPath().getAt(i).lat() < y) && (this.getPath().getAt(j).lat() >= y)) || ((this.getPath().getAt(j).lat() < y) && (this.getPath().getAt(i).lat() >= y))) {
      if (this.getPath().getAt(i).lng() + (y - this.getPath().getAt(i).lat()) / (this.getPath().getAt(j).lat() - this.getPath().getAt(i).lat()) * (this.getPath().getAt(j).lng() - this.getPath().getAt(i).lng()) < x) {
        oddNodes = !oddNodes
      }
    }
  }
  return oddNodes;
}

// === A method which returns the approximate area of a non-intersecting polygon in square metres ===
// === It doesn't fully account for spherical geometry, so will be inaccurate for large polygons ===
// === The polygon must not intersect itself ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Area = function() {
  var a = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var b = this.Bounds();
  var x0 = b.getSouthWest().lng();
  var y0 = b.getSouthWest().lat();
  for (var i = 0; i < this.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    j++;
    if (j == this.getPath().getLength()) {
      j = 0;
    }
    var x1 = this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(new google.maps.LatLng(this.getPath().getAt(i).lat(), x0));
    var x2 = this.getPath().getAt(j).distanceFrom(new google.maps.LatLng(this.getPath().getAt(j).lat(), x0));
    var y1 = this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(new google.maps.LatLng(y0, this.getPath().getAt(i).lng()));
    var y2 = this.getPath().getAt(j).distanceFrom(new google.maps.LatLng(y0, this.getPath().getAt(j).lng()));
    a += x1 * y2 - x2 * y1;
  }
  return Math.abs(a * 0.5);
}

// === A method which returns the length of a path in metres ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Distance = function() {
  var dist = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < this.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
  }
  return dist;
}

// === A method which returns the bounds as a GLatLngBounds ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Bounds = function() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < this.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(this.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  return bounds;
}

// === A method which returns a GLatLng of a point a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = function(metres) {
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
  if (metres < 0) return null;
  if (this.getPath().getLength() < 2) return null;
  var dist = 0;
  var olddist = 0;
  for (var i = 1;
    (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
  }
  if (dist < metres) {
    return null;
  }
  var p1 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 2);
  var p2 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 1);
  var m = (metres - olddist) / (dist - olddist);
  return new google.maps.LatLng(p1.lat() + (p2.lat() - p1.lat()) * m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * m);
}

// === A method which returns an array of GLatLngs of points a given interval along the path ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance = function(metres) {
  var next = metres;
  var points = [];
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres <= 0) return points;
  var dist = 0;
  var olddist = 0;
  for (var i = 1;
    (i < this.getPath().getLength()); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
    while (dist > next) {
      var p1 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 1);
      var p2 = this.getPath().getAt(i);
      var m = (next - olddist) / (dist - olddist);
      points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(p1.lat() + (p2.lat() - p1.lat()) * m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * m));
      next += metres;
    }
  }
  return points;
}

// === A method which returns the Vertex number at a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetIndexAtDistance = function(metres) {
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
  if (metres < 0) return null;
  var dist = 0;
  var olddist = 0;
  for (var i = 1;
    (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
  }
  if (dist < metres) {
    return null;
  }
  return i;
}

// === A function which returns the bearing between two vertices in decgrees from 0 to 360===
// === If v1 is null, it returns the bearing between the first and last vertex ===
// === If v1 is present but v2 is null, returns the bearing from v1 to the next vertex ===
// === If either vertex is out of range, returns void ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Bearing = function(v1, v2) {
  if (v1 == null) {
    v1 = 0;
    v2 = this.getPath().getLength() - 1;
  } else if (v2 == null) {
    v2 = v1 + 1;
  }
  if ((v1 < 0) || (v1 >= this.getPath().getLength()) || (v2 < 0) || (v2 >= this.getPath().getLength())) {
    return;
  }
  var from = this.getPath().getAt(v1);
  var to = this.getPath().getAt(v2);
  if (from.equals(to)) {
    return 0;
  }
  var lat1 = from.latRadians();
  var lon1 = from.lngRadians();
  var lat2 = to.latRadians();
  var lon2 = to.lngRadians();
  var angle = -Math.atan2(Math.sin(lon1 - lon2) * Math.cos(lat2), Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon1 - lon2));
  if (angle < 0.0) angle += Math.PI * 2.0;
  angle = angle * 180.0 / Math.PI;
  return parseFloat(angle.toFixed(1));
}




// === Copy all the above functions to GPolyline ===
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.Contains = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Contains;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.Area = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Area;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.Distance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Distance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.Bounds = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Bounds;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointAtDistance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetIndexAtDistance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetIndexAtDistance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.Bearing = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Bearing;
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

<div id="tools">
  start:
  <input type="text" name="start" id="start" value="Hyderabad" />end:
  <input type="text" name="end" id="end" value="Bangalore" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();" />
  <br />distance (in km):
  <input type="text" name="dist" id="dist" value="0" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="putMarkerOnRoute(parseFloat(document.getElementById('dist').value)*1000);" />km &nbsp;total time:
  <input type="text" name="totalTime" id="totalTime" value="0" />
</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
<div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
  <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
  <div id="total"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Turf, the functions you should take a look at is turf.along. You should be able to resample the path with points every x distance.

http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_along.html

Comment: I'll take a look, but straight line interpolation isn't enough. Google maps will plot a path along road ways, I need pretty accurate points along these driving route. There are a lot of routes, too many to manually input. I'm sure there is a way to get this nicely. The distances are short, within a city so distortions due to projection shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Not really knowing google maps I first thought was to capture the maps, filter for the route colour, fit the line against a b-spline and then sample it however I wish. Getting a b-spline would be absolutely perfect.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you have to pass the path to turf the points are as accurate as the path.